# Which Ubuntu 10.10 package provides the LaTeX class res.cls?

Tags: ubuntu, latex, aptitude, texlive

I am trying to find res.cls! I've been looking for quite a while for res.cls but have not found it.

All signs point to it being in texlive-latex-extra, but as far as I can tell it wasn't provided.

I am in the midst of installing texlive-full just to see what happens, but nonetheless, I would like to know where or if this file is provided.

I know you can get it via CTAN which is where I'm going next if I can't get it from the Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTAN won't give you the name of the Ubuntu package, which effectively **was** `texlive-latex-extra`, because, the package `resume` has been removed from Ubuntu (from Debian too, and even from TeXLive apparently) since lucid 10.04, as shown here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=karmic&searchon=contents&keywords=res.cls

It seems that the package had a license compatibility problem, as explained here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=510749

Comment: Thanks for the research -- it's good to know why it went away at least! For the curious, just download [res.cls](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) and stick it where LaTeX can see it! The location of the *.tex file was good enough for me...